# Can't connect via sftp from windows 10 to ubuntu 18.04 dir(all in LAN) - sftp works internal on server

Tags: lan, openssh, sftp, ubuntu-18.04

ANSWER: `ufw allow 22/tcp`
I'm setting new server(ubuntu server 18.04) for small browser app and I was trying to establish sftp to my windows 10. 
I used this tutorial:https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-enable-sftp-without-shell-access-on-ubuntu-18-04#prerequisites

I succesfully execute sftp ricardo@192.168.10.5 so it works on server. Chroot also works. I can ping my win 10 form server and viceversa, also i see my app on LAN. example: http://192.168.10.5/info.php. Also i can ping particular port using nmap

nmap:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.10.5
Host is up (0.00s latency).
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh
(for port 20) 20/tcp filtered ftp-data
MAC Address: 00:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (VMware)
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 12.15 seconds
```

my_sshd_config:

```
Match User ricardo 
ForceCommand internal-sftp 
PasswordAuthentication yes 
ChrootDirectory /var/www 
PermitTunnel no 
AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
```

from filezilla i get:

```
Status: (...)
Status: (...) 192.168.10.5:20...
response    fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
command:    open "ricardo@192.168.10.5" 20
error:  (...)
error:  (...)
```

simmilar error on Cyberduck(where I seted exact dir to: var/www)
"Connection timed out: connect. The connection attempt was rejected. The server may be down, or your network may not be properly configured"

Comment: You are right i added more data.

Comment: Is your SFTP server on Digital Ocean? Or is it a local network server? + Why are you using port 20?

Comment: No, all is in LAN and i used port 20 becouse i had no idea why port 22 isn't working

Comment: So is your SSH/SFTP server running on port 20? If `sftp ricardo@192.168.10.5` works, then it's not running on port 20. So do not show us irrelevant logs.  Show us logs for port 22.

Comment: I think it's not. In ufw i have this ports as i think open( 80,443/tcp for apache) and (22/tcp for OpenSSH). I wonder why i get this nmap 20/tcp filtered ftp-data form this command >nmap -p 20 192.168.10.5(full log above)

Comment: maybe this is a problem [link]http://prntscr.com/o3q570

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your filezilla log showing `192.168.10.5:20`, try changing your filezilla profile to SFTP and try again.

Comment: port 22(I have this port open in ufw for OpenSSH 22/tcp) gives same error as port 20. I picked protocol SFTP so i think filezilla is on SFTP profile.

Comment: port 22 in the server is working fine if you are able to `sftp` to it. I think you should check your filezilla profile if you are using port 22 and not port 20/21.

Comment: same for 22 as it was for 20 ofc i try to sftp://x.x.x.x `error Status: (...)
Status: (...) 192.168.10.5:20...
response    fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
command:    open "ricardo@192.168.10.5" 22
error:  (...)
error:  (...)`

Comment: it's still showing port 20, can you type `22` in the `Port` box. It should be like this

`Status: Connecting to 172.1.1.109...
Response: fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
Command: open "sftponly@172.1.1.109" 22
Command: Pass: ******
Status: Connected to 172.1.1.109
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command: pwd
Response: Current directory is: "/"
Status: Directory listing of "/" successful`

Comment: http://prntscr.com/o3qil5

Comment: at this point i'm assuming you are able to `sftp` with command from your local machine (where your filezilla installed). try setting the timeout value to 60 seconds, `Edit > Settings > Connection`

Comment: ty for help but I had port 22 blocked somehow - no kappa

Comment: well, at least it's working now